Changes In [FromForm] in .net core 8 where JSON value is not being supported
we have a working .net core api which takes 3 values and processes the. You can see the screenshot below, which is having placeholder for all the fields.In The message field we were able to pass both JSON as well as XML data which our api was able to consume.

Now after we have updated our code to latest .net version you can see that all three input fields are taking string as default value. Moreover the main issue is that is we send a json value in Message field we get a 400 exception saying message field cannot be empty.

My controller code and class code remains same mentioned below :-
   [HttpPost("Produce/v2")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> ProduceForm([FromForm] KafkaPublisherRequest kafkaPublisherRequest)
 {
     if (kafkaPublisherRequest == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return BadRequest();
     }
     _logger.LogInformation($"Started Publishing into Kafka Topic : {kafkaPublisherRequest.Topic}, Key :{kafkaPublisherRequest.Key}");
   //Main code

     return Ok(new ServiceResult(ServiceState.Completed, kafkaPublisherRequest.Key, "Produced Successfully"));
 }

And here is my model class :-
 public class KafkaPublisherRequest
 {
     [Required]

     public string Key { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Message { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Topic { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
 }

When i publish message as {"Name":"Nikhil"} this is the curl url being generated :-
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:5001/xxxxx' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'Key=Key' \
  -F 'Name=Nikhil' \
  -F 'Topic=topic' \
  -F 'Headers='
  -F 'Headers='

Here u can see message field is missing and is considering property name as Nikhil rather than message, hence getting 400 exception because message field is missing.
When i publish message as {"Name"="Nikhil"} this is the curl url being generated :-
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:5001/api/KafkaProducer/Produce/v2' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'Key=Key' \
  -F 'Message={"Name"="Nikhil"}' \
  -F 'Topic=sdajsdasd' \
  -F 'Headers='

This is working fine as the message field is taking values

When using JSON you should set [FromBody].

only one property is meant to be json, i.e. message . all other are plain string.
Also we have one more endpoint as from body. but we need to escape json first before passing it in FromBody, so this endpoint was more helpful. But sadly it stopped working

"we need to escape json". Are you sending plain string and parsing it as json?

in the working code we directly send json. in this updated version we have to escape the double quote of json and then send.

May be I misunderstand, but if you escape the quotes, then JsonSerializer will not not be able to deserialize it, so the [FromForm] won't work. You might however be able to wite a JsonConverterfor your specific purpose.

What does the json value in the message field you refer to look like? Is it a jsonstring? Can you provide a simple example?

{ "metaData": "Nikhil"} this does not work. However
{    "metaData" = "Nikhil"  } works. this first one give a 400 exception. i have given this example because actual data is sensitive.

Adding on that if i escape the json and put in message field like "{\n    "metaData": "Nikhil"\n }" then it works

After testing the code you provided, I found that the three data forms you mentioned can be received by the backend method you provided. You can check whether there are relevant model bindings and other additional configurations in your project configuration.

@YuningDuan did u use .net 8 and latest newtonsoftJSON package ? because previously my code was working and it stopped working recently after updating all nuget package

@NikhilSrivastava Yes, I used .net 8.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson8.0.6 version. In swagger, I filled in the message field with {"metaData": "Nikhil"}, which can be correctly received in my controller method. If the same problem still occurs in your swagger, you can check whether there are other configurations in swaggerUI, and try to use postman to test the API method.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/gwYmQM8I.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/YF0dq89x.png
